# Filter file extension in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter a specific file extension (.xlsx) from the file names in Pandas stored in the same folder. I only want to apply the rest of the script to the files with that extension.

The code that I have created to filter those files is the following one:

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
df_file = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=['Filename'])
df_file

for files in df_file['Filename']:
    if ".xlsx" in files:
        t1_list = df_file["Filename"].str.split(' ')
        print(t1_list)
```

Basically, it reads the filenames and store them in a dataframe (df_file). Then, I try to filter by ".xlsx" and store this on a list of lists (t1_list).

But the output that I get is this one:

[image]

As you can see, it's not filtering anything. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try this, `files = [filename for filename in files if '.xlsx' in filename]`. Right after getting file list from os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like task for [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), in this case you might replace

```
path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
```

using

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
```